# Get rid of empty space in output while parsing the string MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, strip

I have a column with values that I need to strip. The data looks like this:

```
name 
AFBHY | Red
GHYYU | Blue
GHYYL | Black
```

I need to grab just the first part of the string, the desired output is `AFBHY`, `GHYYU` and so on. My code looks like this:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Name`, '|', 1) as `New Name`
```

It returns `AFBHY`  with the white space in the end, how can I modify the query so it returns the value without white space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to trim the whitespace from the returned string, why not use [`TRIM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim):

```
TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Name`, '|', 1)) as `New Name`
```

`TRIM` does exactly what it intimates with it's name, trims characters (spaces by default) from the beginning and end of a string.